# Why does my code have a Limit of 1 with writing it?

Tags: php, sql, arrays, pdo

I have a code who should read all the rows from a mysql database table.
However, it doesn't show all the data from the table.

The $array should contains all the rows , but contains only the first.

I have three row in my module_cmds database

```
+--------+------+----+--------------------+
| module | hash | id | serverId           |
+--------+------+----+--------------------+
| music  |    1 |  1 | 231870365863903232 |
| rule34 |    1 |  2 | 231870365863903232 |
| logs   |    1 |  3 | 231870365863903232 |
+--------+------+----+--------------------+
```

FYI, count($reponses) = 1

Try to change the ORDER BY

FYI, The $array, is use previously in the code, but I don't think it change something

```php
$array = array();
    $reponses = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM module_cmds WHERE serverId=' . $donnees['server_id'] . ' ORDER BY module');
    while ($donnee = $reponses->fetch()){
                $array_param = array();
                $reponses = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM module_params WHERE idModule=' . $donnee['id']);
                while ($donne = $reponses->fetch()){
                        $array_param_in = array( 'param' => $donne['paramName'],
                                                        'value' => $donne['value']);
                        array_push($array_param,$array_param_in);
                }
        $array_in = array( 'module' => $donnee['module'],
                        'hash' => $donnee['hash'],
                        'params' => $array_param);
        array_push($array,$array_in);
    }
```

For an ORDER BY module the answer is

`"modules":[{"module":"logs","hash":"1","params":[]}]`

For an ORDER BY id the answer is

`"modules":[{"module":"music","hash":"1","params":[]}]`

The answer should be

````
"modules":[{"module":"logs","hash":"1","params":[]},
           {"module":"music","hash":"1","params":[]},
           {"module":"rule34","hash":"1","params":[]},]```
````

I think the mistake come from the SQL, but

```sql
'SELECT * FROM module_cmds WHERE serverId = 231870365863903232 ORDER BY module'
```

work fine.

Where is my mistake ? Is it something that I don't know about array in Php ? Some typo ? Some line I forget ?

FYI, I have a similar code where I don't go into in another SQL Table, and it work perfectly there.

Comment: Lookup joins, with a join the DBMS can calculate the result set in one go and you won't need that second query for each row, which is expensive.

Comment: You are overwriting `$reponses` inside the loop, so you will never see the other IDs. Use 2 different variable names or use JOINS as suggested.

Comment: Yes, that was the overwrite the problem. Thanks.
Will try the Join too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the `$reponses` in the second while loop.

Comment: Thnks, that was indeed the problem